# Bootstrap Carousel Pushing and Pulling Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am having some issues with my bootstrap carousel. The images that are currently in it are different sizes and switching between images pushes and pulls content of the page. I want a static height and for the pictures to fill the static height while maintaining aspect ratio. Where have I gone wrong here?

Here is the code from the Carousel:

```html
    <header id="main_carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#main_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#main_carousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="center-block fill" style="background-color:#6A6A6A" src="sample_house_one.jpg" height="inherit" alt="First slide" >
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Next Esate Sale</h3>
            <p>July 8th at 9:00 AM</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="center-block fill" style="background-color:#6A6A6A" src="Sample_house_two.jpg" height="inherit" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Congrats to the new owners</h3>
            <p>Winning bid olny $65,000!!!</p>
          </div>
       </div>
       </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main_carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main_carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>   
 </header>
```

Here is the css I'm using with the carousel everything else is standard Bootstrap theme and css:

```html
html,
body {
    height: 360px;
}

.carousel {
    height: 360px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    min-height:500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}


.item,
.active,
.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}


.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}


footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `max-height: 500px` on your img tag so that way it can't shrink or grow with different picture sizes.

Or better, get rid of the `min-height` and just define `height`. If your pictures are cropping oddly, you might want to either use a `background-image` `div` or crop them to the same size and aspect ratio in an image editing program for the simplest solultion. Since you're using a carousel, cropping the images ahead of time might be the easiest solution.

You could also just allow the div to overflow and hide scroll bars as well, and use `flexbox` to position the image in the middle with `align-items: center` to crop the top and bottom evenly.